# Zend framework file upload illegally uploaded

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files within a normal form with other text fields.

So far, the file gets uploaded to a temp folder but not to my destinationfolder, I always get this error "File 'upload' was illegally uploaded. This could be a possible attack".

I've checked the filename of the tempfile and that has the correct url in the correct folder.

What am I missing here.

```
        $form = new Zend_Form();
        $form->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
        $form->setMethod('post')

             ->addElement('file', 'pdf', array(
                                            'size' => '40',
                                            'label' => 'Select File',
                                            'required' => true,
                                            'validators' => array(
                                                            'Size' => array('min' => 20, 'max' => 1000000)
                                                            )
                                            )
                        )

            ->addElement('submit', 'Save')
        ;

        if ( $this->getRequest()->isPost() ) {
            if ( $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()) ) {
                $id = $form->getValue('name');

                $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
                $uploadDestination = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/uploads/'.$id;

                if(!is_dir($uploadDestination)){
                    mkdir($uploadDestination, 0777, true);
                }

                $upload->setDestination($uploadDestination);
                echo $upload->getFileName();

                if($upload->receive('pdf'))
                {
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($form->getValues());
                    die();
                }
                else
                {
                    $messages = $upload->getMessages();
                    echo implode("\n", $messages);
                    die();
                }
```

$upload->receive('pdf'); is what's not working properly.

Comment: Code looks ok, except that your $id will be null. Anyway, did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

think things may have improved in Zend Framework since this question was asked.

The code below shows a working example of a robust file validation, including customised error messages.

The key point is that the Zend_Form::isValid() method is all you need, **you don't need to validate the file transfer separately**

Your form definition, note that the file validators are added **as if they were normal validators**

```
class Jogs_Form_ImportForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');        
        $this->setAttrib( 'id', 'form-import' );

        $importAction = $this->addElement('radio', 'importAction', array(
            'multiOptions' => array(
                'components' => 'Import components',
                'layouts' => 'Import layouts',
                'layoutComponents' => 'Import layout components',
            ),
            'required'   => true,
            'label'      => 'Import Type:',
        ));

        $upload = $this->addElement( 'file', 'import-file', array( 
            'label' => 'Text (tab delimited) file (.txt)',
            'validators' => array(
            'Size'  => array('max' => 10*1024*1024),
            'Extension'  => array('txt', 'messages' => array(
                 Zend_Validate_File_Extension::FALSE_EXTENSION 
                 => 'file must end with ".txt"' ) ),
            'MimeType' => array( 'text/plain', 'messages' => array( 
                 Zend_Validate_File_MimeType::FALSE_TYPE 
                 => 'file must be text (tab delimited)' ) ),            
            )
        ) );

        $go = $this->addElement('submit', 'go', array(
            'required' => false,
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Go',
        ));
    }
}
```

your controller class

```
class ImportController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction(){
        $form = new Polypipe_Form_ImportForm();
        $this->view->form = $form;

        if ( 
        $this->getRequest()->isPost() 
        && 
        $form->isValid( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) 
        ){
            $data = $form->getValues();
            // get the file info
            $ft = $form->getElement('import-file')->getTransferAdapter();
            $fileInfo = $ft->getFileinfo();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have solved the problem... so i am just giving answer so that anyone who faces this error can find the solution via this valuable post... I faced many difficulties to solve this problem.... Hope it helps someone...

Here the problem is that isValid method is called twice.. once when you call

```
if ( $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()) ) {
}
```

and second in the receive method.. so if you keep the below code outside $form->isValid method than your file will be uploaded..

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$uploadDestination = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/uploads/'.$id;

if(!is_dir($uploadDestination)){
    mkdir($uploadDestination, 0777, true);
}

$upload->setDestination($uploadDestination);
echo $upload->getFileName();

if($upload->receive('pdf'))
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($form->getValues());
    die();
}
else
{
    $messages = $upload->getMessages();
    echo implode("\n", $messages);
    die();
}
```

but still you will get the error when you validate your other elements but your file will be uploaded...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a couple years, but here is the correct answer before you pull out your hair:

```
$form->yourElement->setValueDisabled( true );
```

"Set if the file will be uploaded when getting the value. This defaults to false which will force receive() when calling getValues()."

Comment: In my case the correct answer was to remove the form element altogether. The issue stems from nonrequired `File` element being processed in two nonconnected forms

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   if ( $this->getRequest()->isPost() ) {
        if ( $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()) ) {
            $id = $form->getValue('name');

        $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
        $uploadDestination = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/uploads/'.$id;

        if(!is_dir($uploadDestination)){
            mkdir($uploadDestination, 0777, true);
        }

        $upload->setDestination($uploadDestination);
        echo $upload->getFileName();

        if($upload->receive('pdf'))
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($form->getValues());
            die();
        }
        else
        {
            $messages = $upload->getMessages();
            echo implode("\n", $messages);
            die();
        }
    }
}

        $form = new Zend_Form();
        $form->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
        $form->setMethod('post')

          ->addElement('file', 'pdf', array(
                                    'size' => '40',
                                    'label' => 'Select File',
                                    'required' => true,
                                    'validators' => array(
                                                    'Size' => array('min' => 20, 'max' => 1000000)
                                                    )
                                    )
                )

          ->addElement('submit', 'Save');
```