# Multiple Image Upload one after another in zf2

Tags: php, image, forms, zend-framework2

I am working ZF2 multiple image upload which means i took to file button one below one and trying to upload that one after another but it gives below error.Please help me to find out the error the same code works fine if there is only one file tag in form.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendFirstProjectNew1\module\Stall\src\Stall\Controller\StallController.php on line 989

I am stuck here the details of code are below

**Form**

```
namespace Stall\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class MultipleImageForm extends Form
{
    protected $em;

     public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct('stall');
        $this->setAttribute("method","post");
        $this->setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'file',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'file',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'First Image',
            ),
        )); 

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'image',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'file',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Second Image',
            ),
        )); 
          $this->add(array(
           'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'submit',
        )); 
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
$form->setAttribute('action',$this->url('stall',array('action'=>'multipleimage')));
 $form->prepare();

 echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('file'));
 echo '<br/>';
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('image'));
 echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
 echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

**Controller**

```
 $form = new MultipleImageForm();
         $form->get('submit')->setValue('Submit');
         $request = $this->getRequest();
         if($request->isPost())
         {
            $nonFile = $request->getPost()->toArray();
            $File    = $this->params()->fromFiles('file');
            $data = array_merge_recursive($request->getPost()->toArray(), $request->getFiles()->toArray());
         //   print_r($data);die;
            //set data post and file ...
            $form->setData($data);
            if ($form->isValid()) 
            { 

                $result = new ImageUpload();
                $image1 = (string) $data['file']['name'];
                $image2 = (string) $data['image']['name'];

                if(!empty($image1))
                {
                    $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
                    $adapter->setDestination('public/img/upload/'); // Returns all known internal file information
                    $adapter->addFilter('File\Rename', array('target' => $adapter->getDestination() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$image1 , 'overwrite' => true));
                    //$adapter->addFilter('File\Rename', array('target' => $adapter->getDestination() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."_upload123".$favicon , 'overwrite' => true));
                    if(!$adapter->receive()) 
                    { 
                        $messages = $adapter->getMessages(); 
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Image Uploaded";
                    }
                }

                if(!empty($image2))
                {
                    $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
                    $adapter->setDestination('public/img/upload/'); // Returns all known internal file information
                    $adapter->addFilter('File\Rename', array('target' => $adapter->getDestination() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$image2 , 'overwrite' => true));
                    //$adapter->addFilter('File\Rename', array('target' => $adapter->getDestination() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."_upload123".$favicon , 'overwrite' => true));
                    if(!$adapter->receive()) 
                    { 
                        $messages = $adapter->getMessages(); 
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Image Uploaded";
                    }
                }
            }

         }
         return array('form' => $form);
```

Comment: Which line in your controller is line `989`?

Comment: $adapter->addFilter('File\Rename', array('target' => $adapter->getDestination() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$image1 , 'overwrite' => true)); this is line  989

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If line **989** in your controller is this line:

```
$adapter->addFilter('File\Rename', array('target' => $adapter->getDestination() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$image1 , 'overwrite' => true));
```

And you get this error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendFirstProjectNew1\module\Stall\src\Stall\Controller\StallController.php on line 989

Then one of the variables on that line is an array instead of a string:

So either `$adapter->getDestination()` or `$image1` is not of type string. You should debug your code and refactor so you get a string for both those variables.

Comment: $adapter->getDestination() was array i modified that by the array but now one image is uploading and it gives error ( [fileUploadErrorAttack] => File 'php1013.tmp_c-300x229.jpg' was illegally uploaded. This could be a possible attack )

Comment: @BeDeveloper That is another question.

Comment: i am stuck from last two days so what to do now

Comment: @BeDeveloper You current question was solved with my answer, so you have to accept the answer and move on with your new issue. For example **[this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534301/zend-framework-file-upload-illegally-uploaded)** is dealing with the same problem but I bet there are more questions about the same issue.